# If condition for dynamic variable in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a input checkbox field, where its name generate dynamically using JavaScript.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options_'.$j.'"  class="check">
```

Now, I want to check whether any checkbox is checked or not in if condition.
I have written the following code. But it is not working. Please help me to correct the code.

```
for($i = 0; $i<=1; $i++)
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['options_ '.$i]))
        {
            echo $error;
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Is this is the correct format?

Comment: Remove second `$i++;`

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i<=count($_POST); $i++)
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['options_ '.$i]))
        {
            echo $error;
        }
    }`

Comment: why don't you go for `<input type="checkbox" name="options['.$j.']" class="check">` in your HTML, now you can use `count ($_POST['options'])` directly instead of this much code

Answer (score 1):

the    $i++; is not neccesary the one in the for will do it for you